# Записать дата фрейм в столбце которого только неотрицательные значения и пустые

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, анализ-данных, обработка-данных

Нужно записать в файл эксель дата фрейм, в котором значения неотрицательны или пустые ячейки. Пробывала так:

```
df3[(df3['Количество дней между ТУ и заключением договора'] >= 0) |(df3['Количество дней между ТУ и 
заключением договора']=np.none)].to_excel('NEW_Выгрузка_истории_по_заявкам_ОЭК_2019_2020.xlsx')
```

и так:

```
(df3['Количество дней между ТУ и 
    заключением договора']=NaN)
```

и так:

```
(df3['Количество дней между ТУ и 
    заключением договора'].empty
```

Больше нет идей.

Comment: ой, я днем его принемала, а сейчас обнаружила, что нет...сорян

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь методом [Series.isna()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isna.html):

```
(df3
 [(df3['Количество дней между ТУ и заключением договора'] >= 0)
   | 
  (df3['Количество дней между ТУ и заключением договора'].isna())]
 .to_excel('NEW_Выгрузка_истории_по_заявкам_ОЭК_2019_2020.xlsx'))
```

или более короткий вариант - сначала заполняем `NaN`ы нулем, после этого проверяем:

```
(df3
 [df3['Количество дней между ТУ и заключением договора'].fillna(0) >= 0]
 .to_excel('NEW_Выгрузка_истории_по_заявкам_ОЭК_2019_2020.xlsx'))
```